# urls.py Django не получается сделать переход на страницу

Tags: django, django-urls

путь в urls.py

```
path('сustomers-orders/<int:pk>/customers-orders-date/', views.CustomersOrdersDateView.as_view(), name='customers_orders_date'),
```

в адресную строку передаются данные из datepicker

http://192.168.0.178:8000/customers-orders/36/customers-orders-date/?datefilter=06%2F14%2F2020+-+06%2F20%2F2020

но получаю ошибку Page not found (404)

views.py

```
class CustomersOrdersDateView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'сustomers_orders_date.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['list_orders'] = Order.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        kwargs['list_customers'] = Customer.objects.all().order_by('name')
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Логично, slug же нет в URL'е, но есть в паттерне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path('customers-orders/<int:pk>/', include([
    path('', views.CustomersOrdersView.as_view(), name='customers_orders'),
    path('customers-orders-date/', views.CustomersOrdersDateView.as_view(), name='customers_orders_date'),
])),
```